# SMO algorithm running into infinite loop?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, svm

I'm interest in building an SVM multi class classifier, so I am currently implementing 
Sequential minimal optimization SMO.

My implementation is based on the pseudo code in 
`Fast Training of Support Vector Machines using Sequential Minimal Optimization" by John C. Platt

I observed that for certain training examples. The Smo may diverge and run into an infinite loop
The following loop in the main routine

numChanged = 0;

examineAll = 1;

while (numChanged > 0 || examineAll >0) {…}

may  run into an infinite loop.

Is there there clue or criterion to prevent the smo algorithm  routine from running into an infinite loop?

I would like to thank you for your answer.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a max iteration condition if you want:

```
while ((numChanged > 0 || examineAll) && iter < MaxIter)
```

but for most cases it shouldn't run into an infinite loop, this is the full Platt's pseudocode:

```
while (numChanged > 0 || examineAll)
{
    numChanged = 0;
    // Adding curly brackets for better readability
    if (examineAll)
    {
        loop I over all training examples
        numChanged += examineExample(I);
    }
    else
    {
        loop I over examples where alpha is not 0 & not C
        numChanged += examineExample(I);
    }

    if (examineAll == 1)
    {
        examineAll = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        examineAll = 1;
    }
}
```

Notice that what it is doing is performing an iteration to examine the example and the next one do the same just to those examples where alpha is not 0 or C. If nothing changes after the "examine all" iteration, the while loop condition will be false hence stopping the loop.

So, for that to be in a infinite loop there must be a corner case (probably a numerical error) that introduce oscillations making examples to change during the examine all phase but not changing in the "examine only alpha == 0 and C".

Usually if the data is normalized in [-1,1] or [0,1] and the parameters of the algorithm have reasonable values, those corner cases would be rare. In any case, if you want to be extra careful you can put the max-iter safety net.

Comment: @user3048838 Anytime :)